# JQuery Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Il trying to filter Events on a calendar using check boxes and JQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.scrollable-menu :checkbox').click(function (){
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
      $('.alert').hide();
      $('.more').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

This is what i have upto now, i know its not much. This works fine but from here i need it to some how select the li.alerts which have certain background colors

```
$('div[style~="backgroundColor: red;"]').show()
```

but every event has a different background colour so this needs to change some how i have stored the color in the name of the check boxes. I also need the script to allow more than one checkbox selected at the same time

```
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li name="{{category.color}}"><input name="{{category.color}}" value="your_value" type="checkbox"><div style="color:#{{category.color}};">{{ category.name }}{{ category.color }}</div></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So what's the confusion?

Comment: There should hardly ever be a need to select elements based on the current values of specific CSS properties. Use a different way to select those elements, f.e. a common class. And FYI, `li` elements don’t have a `name` attribute.

Comment: @Justinas keep guessing AllDay :p

Comment: @Justinas I don't know how to change the value dynamically eg, if the user shows meetings, all the red events should show(meetings are red). then how do i make this work for more than one selection. if the user clicks meetings and important jobs(red) how do i show them both?

Comment: @CBroe ah sorry, Every Event has a class of alert but they all have inline styling depending on the event so the only difference between events is the colour.

Comment: _“eg, if the user shows meetings, all the red events should show(meetings are red)”_ – that is _exactly_ why you should be using classes in the first place. Those elements have different “meanings” resp. types of content, so a class is more than justified.

Comment: @CBroe i have changed them to classes, but how do i show something depending on what checkbox they select. sorry im kinda new to jQuery you probabley already realised haha

Comment: You could put the class name into the value attribute of the checkbox – so that you know which elements to show based on that selection.

Comment: @AllDay First, you need to explain how this calendar is presented. Is it a `<table>`, `<ol>` (if so, weekly I hope), a popup, etc.? Second, depending on how  it's presented, we probably need HTML, we have no idea what `.alert` or `.more` and how they relate to the checkbox, DOM, or any of the multiple checkboxes you want to group together. Third, when you say multiple checkboxes, do you mean as in all checkboxes in a day, a week, a month, or type, or priority etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting by CSS style (what if you change color?) apply some specific classes to elements and use them.

```
$('.jobs.main').show();
$('.jobs.secundary').hide();
$('.meetings, .jobs').show();
[...]
```

Example of using classes for filtering:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var filters = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    if (filters.length) {
      $('.event').hide();
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        $('.event.' + $(this).data('type')).show();
      });
    } else {
      $('.event').show();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.job {
  color: red;
}
.meeting {
  color: blue;
}
.job.meeting {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event meeting job">Job Meeting</div>
<div class="event job">Important job</div>
<div class="event meeting">Meeting with client</div>
<div class="event call">Call to client</div>
<hr/>Filter:
<br/>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-type="job" />Jobs
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-type="call" />Calls
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-type="meeting" />Meetings
</label>
```

Comment: I have just assigned them all unique classes for each type of event, the problem i am having now is how do i define each checkbox to show a single event. would this be multiple if statements(seems a bit old fashioned) Sorry i haven't got very much knowledge of jquery